# Problems with import Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, module

I have problem with importing matplotlib.
I am using: WPy64-3850 and sypder.

```
 File "D:\tkminek_local\PYTHON\DAMPING\pokus.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

  File "D:\instalacky\WPy64-3850\python-3.8.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 822, in <module>
    rcParamsDefault = _rc_params_in_file(

  File "D:\instalacky\WPy64-3850\python-3.8.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 727, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:

  File "D:\instalacky\WPy64-3850\python-3.8.5.amd64\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)

  File "D:\instalacky\WPy64-3850\python-3.8.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 701, in _open_file_or_url
    fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)

  File "D:\instalacky\WPy64-3850\python-3.8.5.amd64\lib\ntpath.py", line 293, in expanduser
    path = os.fspath(path)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not WindowsPath
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a conflict of a platform-specific library, that creates WindowsPath object.
In your case i would try those:

- different version of matplotlib

```py
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib==some_version
```

- reinstalling python
- intall different python version

You should try to figure out where windows path object is created, so that you can change it to string (using str), that might resolve the issue.

I would also tried

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```